# повторяющиеся символы +ооп

Tags: c++, математика

Задание сказали сделать через классы и циклы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

попробовал сделать найдя все нечетные сотни, вышло как то так через for

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;

    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
    {
        a = i / 100;

        if (a % 2 != 0)
            cout << i << "\n";
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

прошу помочь организовать это через классы и методы и еще хотя бы с 1 циклом while / do...while

Comment: @pavel это последнее, остальное слишком нагло спрашивать ибо я примерно не знаю как их реализовать:)

Comment: я бы по аналогии с ответом Harry из прошлого вопроса делал, отличий почти что и нету.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То что вы пишете, заносите в функцию и делайте функцию членом класса. Это самый простой вариант:

```
class Odd {
    const int first, last;
public:
    Odd(const int lower, const int upper)
        : first(lower), last(upper) {}
    void show_all() const
    {
        int i = first;
        if (!(i & 1)) ++i;
        while (i <= last) {
            cout << i <<'\n';
            i += 2;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{   
    Odd  a(100, 120);
    a.show_all();
    return 0;
}
```

При решении других подобных задач, прочитайте еще про `функторы`, `классы-композиторы`, изучайте варианты, предложенным пользователем  `Harry` в предыдущем вашем вопросе ну и т.д. Тут вопрос задавать нужно, чтоб понять как подойти к решению или как исправить ошибку, а не для того, чтоб каждый раз за вас решали...